# Deploying JARs with Java 9 and above (JDK11 in this case) (JLink confusion?)

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a Java veteran, but I've been using JDK8 for a long time. I've decided I finally want to upgrade, so I've been using Java11. I've been enjoying the new features, but I've gotten the point where I need to deploy my software.

In the past I would export a runnable JAR from Eclipse and bundle it with an appropriate JRE. Then I'd use both to run the software from an OS-specific program (e.g. an EXE file that fires up the bundled JRE with the given JAR). Of course, now this isn't really an option because JREs are a thing of the past. Supposedly the new system in its place is much lighter weight and straight forward, the only problem is I can't figure out how to actually use it.

I've been reading about how to deploy programs with JDK9 and above and have seen people mention JLink and link documentation to it, but I can't seem to find a straight answer on how to just simply export a runnable JAR. The thing is - I don't really need all of the module support and don't really want to have to configure it. Is there a tool for simply exporting something I can run? How is this done now?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm just genuinely confused at how this all works and can't really find anything online that lays it out in a clear and concise way. There's a lot of documentation on JLink and what it does, but I haven't really found anything that explains the root purpose for all of it.

**TL;DR; how do I export working Java programs with JDK9 and above using Eclipse (latest version)?**

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please take into account that Java applications packaged with `jlink` have the disadvantage of not only causing additional work, but may also prevent the installation of extensions (e.g. in contrast to Eclipse/OSGi where plug-ins/bundles can be installed, updated, etc. at runtime). The saving of a few MB should not be an issue these days and the start time can be reduced by about a third using the OpenJ9 Java VM and its shared class cache instead of using Oracle's HotSpot VM.

Comment: What are you suggesting I do then? I have no idea how to get a program to run with JDK11 at this point. All of the Jlink stuff is breaking/refusing to run for me anyway.

Comment: Assuming you do not use something that has been removed in Java 9 or higher (e.g. XML binding), just add the argument `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` to your command line, e.g. `java --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -jar myApp.jar`. Since Java 9 you can add libraries (JARs) to the classpath (as before) or to the modulepath (new). In the past Oracle provided Java JREs for different operating systems. Now, Oracle wants you to ship a JRE with your product instead and provides updates at no cost for a version only for a short time. Alternatively, get a free JREs from [here](https://adoptopenjdk.net/).

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm just gonna move onto OpenJDK. From what I'm reading, it sounds like it'll work better for me anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent literally months on trying to figure out how to create a single, clickable executable using Java 9+. I now conclude that it is impossible. Whether you use jlink directly yourself, or indirectly via Maven or Gradle, the result is that jlink produces a full directory structure that you are left to "distribute to your users" (somehow, I guess magically, since nothing in Java 9+ tells you anything about how you're supposed to do this). Then, once your user (somehow) has this directory on their machine, they are forced to invoke runtime-image-directory/bin/your-program-name. As though your user is a programmer who is happy to have to install a directory structure, and drill down to invoke a specific file name, which is buried in a directory with lots of other files, rather than being a user who USED to be able to simply double-click on a .jar file to run it. This makes me really wonder if whomever designed all this thought at all about the "user experience". The fact that there appears, as of Java 9+, to be NO WAY to simply deliver ONE file (such as a .jar) to users, together with the fact that just BUILDING this "runtime image" is fantastically complicated, means that developers are going to abandon Java in droves. It really seems to me that the brainiacs at Oracle simply didn't think this through. They have created a death knell to Java by making something onerous for developers to build and distribute, and onerous for users to invoke. I don't see how this situation can be allowed to remain without Java ultimately dying off. Somebody please correct me if I am missing something here, but I've spent months now trying to figure out how to create a runnable jar in Java 9+, USING MODULES, and it appears there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> ...how to just simply export a runnable JAR.

Well, if you're not planning on using modules for your application classes, the JAR part should be the same as before. You basically just have to create your own JRE using `jlink`, e.g.:

```
jlink --add-modules java.se --output jre
```

That would create a `jre` folder with a runtime image that includes all the `java.se` modules.

You can then bundle that with your JAR like before.

---

The interesting part here is that you can pick and choose which modules go into this runtime image. `java.se` is an aggregator module that transitively includes a bunch of other modules. But you could also specify your own specific list of modules, leaving out some of the ones you don't need, making the final runtime image smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll try it out and accept the answer if this works out. Is there any way to have JLink check the imports in the JAR and decide what parts to include on its own?

Comment: @Brasch Not `jlink`, but you can use `jdeps --print-module-deps <jar>` to get a list of needed modules. If you have your own module, you could pass that to `jlink` instead and it would automatically include all needed modules, plus your module in the runtime image (i.e. no need for a separate JAR file)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it all out and report back on here when I'm done.

Comment: @John Vernee, I've ran into a problem. When I attempt to run jlink, this is printed by the command prompt (windows): ``'jlink' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`` When I use java -version, it says I'm using 10, so this shouldn't be an issue, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1255915/java-9-jlink-command-not-found. For those reading this who had the same issue, be sure to call the jlink commands from the /bin folder of your Java installation.